# Issue in VS2010 beta or Dll?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am facing a strange issue. I have created 5 projects in a solution which are of type Windows Class Library, Windows Console Application, Windows WPF Application, Workflow Activity Library and Sequential Workflow Console Application. I have added reference of same dll in all five projects. Without writing any code I build the projects.

Three of them Windows Class Library, Windows Console Application and  Windows WPF Application build successfuly while two Workflow Activity Library and Sequential Workflow Console Application projects gives this error.

XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task: '`Could not load file or assembly 'assembly name`' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

The `DLL` i am referring to has runtime version 2.0 and setting specific version = true doesn't change anything.

So is this issue in Vs beta version or something is wrong with `DLL`?

Comment: Did the empty projects build before you added the library reference?

Comment: yes i was able to build them successfully before adding the references